# How it's a sigma-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Let $B \subseteq X$

Prove that  $\mathcal{E}_B=\{A \subseteq X|B \subseteq A$ or $B\subseteq A^c\}$

My answer is:
1) Because X is a nonempty set therefore $X \in \mathcal{E}_B$

I'm not sure how to show the two other conditions. This subject is new for me.

PS: I've uploaded the task (I don't know if you can see it)

Comment: Prove that "what"???

Answer (score 0):

$\mathcal{E}_B$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra in general.

Take $X = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ and $B = \{1, 2\}$.
Then $\{2\} \subseteq \{1, 2\} \subseteq B$ so $\{2\} \in \mathcal{E}_B$. Also, $\{3\} \subseteq \{3, 4\} \subseteq B^c$ so $\{3\} \in \mathcal{E}_B$.
But, $\{2\} \cup \{3\} = \{2, 3\}$ is not is $\mathcal{E}_B$ as it is not a subset of $B$ or $B^c$. We see that $\mathcal{E}_B$ is not closed under finite unions, so it is not a $\sigma$-algebra.

$\mathcal{E}_B$ is however closed under complementation which is evident from the symmetry of its definition, and contains $X$ because $B \subseteq X$.